# Why and/or when to avoid intransitive() or notTransitive()?

Tags: sbt

I currently have an SBT subproject that needs a dependency only at compile-time, so I think it's a good place to use `intransitive` so that projects that use it won't need to download that dependency.

However, according to the [SBT reference manual](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Library-Management.html):

> In some instances, you may find that the dependencies listed for a project aren’t necessary for it to build. Projects using the Felix OSGI framework, for instance, only explicitly require its main jar to compile and run. Avoid fetching artifact dependencies with either intransitive() or notTransitive()

The wording is a bit confusing because it discourages the use of `transitive()` or `notTransitive()` without explaining why or when (all the time?).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you're just misreading the sentence. "Avoid fetching artifact dependencies with either intransitive() or notTransitive()" is intended to mean "If you want to avoid fetching artifact dependencies, the way to do this is with either intransitive() or notTransitive()".

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be the accepted one

Answer (score 4):

`notTransitive` is just an alias to `intransitive` and is defined like this:

```
def notTransitive = intransitive
```

in [Configuration.scala](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/9c442d3aed53bdc89db1ada9d5b204bf02adb339/ivy/src/main/scala/sbt/Configuration.scala). It's just a matter of preference like `must` and `should` in Specs2, or `size` and `length` in Scala collections.

Usually using default transitive dependency behavior is preferred because it requires less configuration and maintenance - SBT will pull all required dependencies for you. If you decide to upgrade the version of a primary dependency you don't have to manually upgrade all transitive dependencies as well. However, sometimes you either don't need to have a dependency in some scopes, like `Specs2` should be usually available for `test` scope only. In other cases your environment provides all required dependencies and you can make your packaged artifact smaller by not packaging them. Transitive dependency management fits the majority of the use-cases and leads to less errors during runtime (missing implementation, Class not found) and that's why it's preferred. If you know what you are doing there is nothing wrong using `intransitive` option.

Note that by setting `intransitive` on a dependency you are still fetching that dependency if it's in the library dependencies of the project. You are only avoiding fetching its transitive/sub dependencies.

If your SBT subproject builds fine with that dependency and your other SBT project uses that subproject without needing that dependency directly then simply do not include that library dependency into the second project. You don't need to do intransitive conf in that case.

In your case it sounds like dependent projects or environment will provide those transitive dependencies. In that case use `intransitive` if you are technically just compiling against an API like Servlets or some log library.

Comment: Sorry, this didn't answer my question. I was aware the at the 2 do the same thing, but was wondering why using either of them ("or") is discouraged.

Answer (score 4):

`intransitive` is discouraged because :

- downstream users don't see it in their POM and it might break their runtime,
- even if they know what dependency to add, its version won't be synced with upstream.

`provided` is reserved for when the dependency is expected to be in the runtime, e.g. an application container.

I would reserve `intransitive` for cases where the dependency is not needed in the runtime, only at compile-time. e.g. compiler annotations

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect use case for the "provided" configuration. In your project, depend on the library (say 'foo') in the `"provided"` configuration like this:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.foo" %% "foo" % "1.0" % "provided"
```

This will add `foo` to the classpath at compile-time, but won't register `"org.foo" %% "foo" % "1.0"` in the metadata (pom) of your artifact. Therefore, users of your project will not depend on foo, simply because they won't see it at all.